# Adding children to a Wrap() based on the values inside a JSON field

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to display a Chip for every item inside the "genre_ids" field of my JSON file.
In my case, the field 'genre_ids' contains 3 values: [20, 35, 72]
So 3 Chips must be created.

This is what I was attempting:

```
 List<Widget> genres(BuildContext context){        

switch (movie['genre_ids'].contains()) {
                case '20' :
                genres.children.add(
                    Chip(
              
                        avatar: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Icon(Icons.nights_stay, color: Colors.black38,)
                        ),
              
                        label: Text('Mystery'),
                    )
                );
     case '35' :
            genres.children.add(
                Chip(
          
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(Icons.happy, color: Colors.black38,)
                    ),
          
                    label: Text('Comedy'),
                )
            );
     case '72' :
            genres.children.add(
                Chip(
          
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(Icons.playful, color: Colors.black38,)
                    ),
          
                    label: Text('Animation'),
                )
            );
    break;
              }
}
```

But it's giving me errors.
I have used switch statements very rarely so it's kind of new for me.

Comment: I solved this by using many if else statements. If the genre_id isn't found, it returns an empty contanier.
But it would still be cool to know how to achieve the same result with the switch statement.

Comment: If your `switch` block doesn't cover all cases, you need to have `default`. Have a look at the [document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html)